# Looking to install Vulkan on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04, amdgpu, vulkan

I am looking to install Vulkan with a Pitcairn Radeon HD 7870 GPU - is [this](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) procedure from AMD to install their driver still relevant, or is there a better way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't use the < dist-upgrade > Have you installed it yet ?

Comment: Hi - no i havent. Is everything after that step ok?

Comment: sure. If you run into any problems let me know ;)

Comment: thanks An0n - just tried it, and vulkan borked my dekstop environment i think. i run budgie, and every time i started i could get the lightdm log in screen, but couldnt actually log in. i also couldnt bring up the vty using ctrl+alt+fn. i eventually just removed it